# I am an Indian going to Nigeria

Tags: dubai

I'm an Indian and going to Nigeria but my pnr is multi itinerary that means I will be flying by air Arabia to shrjah and then sharjah to Dubai. In sharjah layover is 10 hours while in Dubai it is 2 hours but I need to change my flight in Dubai and I will be flying by Egypt air. So, I want to know weather I need a transit visa for changing flights in Dubai or not?? Thanks